# React Service Worker: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

I'm customizing my service worker in a React app created with CRA.

The only change I made was to create a function to poll for live updates. So, my file looks like this:

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read https://cra.link/PWA

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/)
);

const POLLING_LOOP_MS = 30000;

type Config = {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
};

export function register(config?: Config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config)
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }

        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };

      pollLiveSWUpdates(registration);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    });
}

function pollLiveSWUpdates(registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) {
  setInterval(async () => {
    await registration.update();
  }, POLLING_LOOP_MS);
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

So, when there is a new update, I trigger the `onUpdate` to show a toast in the application. When I click on the Update button in my toast, I skip the waiting status and refresh the page, so the new service work is registered and running. This is working properly then.

However, if a new update is found and I just refresh the page without skipping the current waiting by using my toast, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

It seems that the current service worker is trying to get a cached chunk js file that is not available anymore. And the response for that file is an HTML of my index.html. I had some CSP and cache-control policies for my headers, but I have removed all of them and the error persists.

And some times the error is different for the same case:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5001/static/js/[DASH].chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

The same thing happens if I try to use the built-in serviceWorkerRegistration.ts file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any time you see that error, you can be that you got a 404 or 403 HTML response, but you forgot to write code that verifies that you actually got a valid result before continuing your codepath. Especially given the second error you're showing: clearly you got an HTML page from your server, not the .js file you expected. Look at your dev tools network tab and see what you got instead, because I can guarantee you your filename is incorrect and you're just getting served a 404 page.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah, in the network request for that js file specifically is returning the index.html file instead of the js content. 

But, this request is being made by the service worker itself. As I dont have any cache-control enable, why is it returning an HTML instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sometimes it is showing this error: 

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5001/static/js/[DASH].chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Yes, and that error says "dude, I can't run an HTML file as a script, it's an HTML file, not javascript" so: fix whatever code is responsible for building the `src` links. It's clearly building the wrong one(s) right now: look at the error. No build system is going to use the _literal_ name `[DASH].chunk.js`, that "[DASH]" part is super obviously supposed to be a placeholder for an identifier that should have been replaced, but wasn't, probably due to a configuration error either on your part, or your build tools' part.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for yuur reply. So, after digging more I found out that the service worker is not caching the previous js chunk files that are generated in the build process. If I test it using the `http-server`  everything works as expected. But serving the app with my ndoe express app is causing it to try to load the cached files but they dont exist. My node express app has this: 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
});

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you think it could be something related to that? Because what is happening is: when I reload the page without updating the service worker, it caches the index.html and it tries to load the cached js chunks, then I get that error. But it should have them cached, right? And this does not happen if I serve the app using the `http-server` package

Comment: If after working based on a hint, you're still stuck: if it's the same problem, edit your post to work in that new information, but if it's different enough, that's a new post. In this case: no idea, your post doesn't say anything about your app.js, or how you're bundling, etc. etc. so we'd be guessing. If you suspect caching is at fault: reduce your codebase to a [mcve] centered on caching, and then you probably have something that's different enough from this post to warrant posting a new question instead.